# Attributes of Object are updated to null on lazy-loaded AccordionPanel Component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true">`on my page. When submitting the page the attributes of not-loaded-objects get null-values applied. I don't want this behaviour, as the values are correct in DB and on server-side. Why does not showing them in Browser results in nulling them on the server-side. I think this values shouldn't be applied, because they have not been rendered.

My xhtml (snippet):

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" value="#{controller.selectedObject.list}" var="listItem">
  <p:selectOneMenu value="#{list.market}" disabled="#{controller.selectedObject.isDisabled}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{marketSelectItems.selectItems}" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Assuming `controller.selectedObject.list` contains two entries of `BeanA` where both have a filled property `market`.
Now when having `controller.selectedObject.isDisabled` set to true my log states:

```
10:21:12,565 TRACE [de.bss.dm.kairos.gui.phaselistener.AnyPhaseListener:25] UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 before Phase
10:21:12,577 TRACE [de.bss.dm.kairos.gui.phaselistener.AnyPhaseListener:20] UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 after Phase
```

And everything works fine, the values stay assigned.

But when having `controller.selectedObject.isDisabled` set to false my log states:

```
10:21:51,210 TRACE [de.bss.dm.kairos.gui.phaselistener.AnyPhaseListener:25] UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 before Phase
10:21:51,228 INFO  [stdout] (default task-46) setMarket(de.mypackage.Market@2ed)
10:21:51,251 INFO  [stdout] (default task-46) setMarket(null)
10:21:51,265 TRACE [de.bss.dm.kairos.gui.phaselistener.AnyPhaseListener:20] UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 after Phase
```

resulting in persisting wrong values in DB, loosing information.
When i open the second `p:accordionPanel`-Tab, resulting in loading data, all is fine, the second `BeanA`-Object is assigned the correct `Market`-Object.

HTML when not working:

```
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" role="tablist" data-widget="widget_generalForm_instrumentDetailTabs_listingpanel">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true">
    headertext loremipsum
  </h3>
  <div id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel:0:listingtab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div>loaded CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
     headertext loremipsum
  </h3>
  <div id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel:1:listingtab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel_active" name="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel_active" value="0">
</div>
```

After clicking on second tab (or having `dynamic="false"`)

```
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" role="tablist" data-widget="widget_generalForm_instrumentDetailTabs_listingpanel">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true">
    headertext loremipsum
  </h3>
  <div id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel:0:listingtab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div>loaded CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
     headertext loremipsum
  </h3>
  <div id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel:1:listingtab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div>loaded CONTENT OF TAB 2!!!
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel_active" name="generalForm:instrumentDetailTabs:listingpanel_active" value="0">
</div>
```

Setting `dynamic="false"` on `p:accordionPanel` also results in correct behaviour, though I can't use it. The accordionPanels contain a lot of components, resulting in page-size of >1MB when controller.selectedObject.list contains about 15 items.

How should I deal with this Problem? Why are my values updated though they are not rendered/loaded?

Version information: Primefaces 5.0, WildFly 8.1.0.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by adding `process="@this @(.myfakeclass)"` to my `p:commandButton` and using
`<p:outputPanel styleClass="myfakeclass">`. This results in HTML `<div>` elements styled by a class that doesn't exist. In non-loaded panels this class is not rendered, thus not processed.

I still think it is a bug in Primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in primefaces. I experience it in version 3.4.1 and I've been unable to upgrade from that due to other bugs. It's possible it has been fixed since then as you don't say which version you're using.

There are two workarounds I use. For small components, I set dynamic="false" and if necessary hide the component in the html until needed. For larger components, I put a null check in the setter and make sure the value can never be legitimately set to null.

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 5.0, added this information to initial post.  `dynamic="false"` is not an option, the HTML growl too large.  A null-check in the setter would result in not being able to null the value. Sadly this is needed..